# To be attained at/on?

Tags: prepositions, mathematics

I'm writing a math paper, so it would probably be easier to answer this question with some background in math. Assume I have a set of "things" and some function turning these things into numbers. I'm interested in two values: the maximum value of this function and the "thing" the maximum is attained **on/at**. What's the right choice of preposition here? If there are multiple "things" with the same value, do I say "things the maximum is attained **on/at**" with the same preposition or change it somehow? Also, is this phrase "the thing the maximum is attained **on/at**" good enough or maybe I'd rather say "the thing **on/at** which the maximum is attained"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice of preposition is largely dependent on your said mathematical "things":

- The function *f* attains its maximum value **at the point** *x=0*.
- The function *f* attains its maximum value **on the interval** [0,1].
- The function *f* attains its maximum value **in the subset** *M*.

Alternatively, one may write

- *x=0* is the point **at which** the maximum value of the function *f* is attained.
- *[0,1]* is the interval **on which** the maximum value of the function *f* is attained.
- *M* is the subset **in which** the maximum value of the function *f* is attained.

Though, in mathematical writing, one usually shuns beginning a sentence or phrase with a mathematical symbol. Hence

- The point *x=0* is the point **at which** the maximum value of the function *f* is attained.

is always preferred in mathematical writing. See [How to Write Mathematics by Halmos](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Eazoff/courses/halmos.pdf).

If the last formulation sounds repetitive, go with the first set of phrasings.

Comment: So, you say phrase "the point the maximum is attained at" is not a good idea?

Comment: I would say "the point at which the maximum is attained".

Answer (score 0):

*To attain at*: simply because it's an ending point. A point ***at*** which you arrive (or try to arrive). Using *on* makes it sound like a starting point, rather than a maximum (or minimum, both are extremes).
When comparing all of the results, I'd still go for *at*: *the "thing" at which the highest value was attained was X*. There's no reason why the adverb should change here.